# Trouble with Ubuntu 12.10 post installation

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, dell, laptop, inspiron

Dell Inspiron 5150 Laptop
Pentium 4 3.x MHz processor
1.5 GB RAM
30 GB Toshiba HD in 3 partitions: 32 MB FAT for Dell utility, 14.x GB NTFS for Win XP Pro SP2, 14.x ext4 for Linux

I went through the installation procedures for Ubuntu v 12.10 as outlined here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Everything went as described in the documentation (well done documentation by the way). I didn't have any problems with the installation. However once completed, I rebooted the laptop and I got to the login screen just fine. Once I entered the login ID & password, the screen went black and the mouse and keyboard "froze." I could not do anything.

I have been digging around here on the "questions and answers" section of the support/knowledge base of Ubuntu. I have seen that several others have experienced something similar. However, there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer or solution to the problem. What are my options at this point?

Any and all suggestions, hints, solutions, etc are welcome.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Can you edit that in to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have Low spec'd PC. Unity is too much for your PC to handle. Try installing xubuntu or Lubuntu. They are really fast and lighweight.

P.S i would recommend Installing Xubuntu.